# Issue with circular reference in SQL and need an alternative via SQL or a spark loop in Databricks

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I need a solution that either uses spark to loop through each row or a way of using SQL to work around the circular reference that I have with the columns I need.

I want to calculate the 3 following columns:

- Points = BasePoints - BurnRateCumul
- BurnRate = Points / DaysLeft
- BurnRateCumul = Running total of BurnRate

The base data looks like the below:

| Date | BasePoints | DaysLeft |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 6 | 82 |
| 2023-01-02 | 6 | 81 |
| 2023-01-03 | 6 | 80 |
| 2023-01-04 | 11 | 79 |
| 2023-01-05 | 55 | 78 |
| 2023-01-06 | 55 | 77 |
| 2023-01-07 | 55 | 76 |
| 2023-01-08 | 55 | 75 |

I have been trying to do this using SQL in Databricks using Windowed functions but haven't been able to get the numbers to match up.

A basic example of the type of code I've been using to demonstrate the circular reference:

```
Select
  bb.Date,
  bb.BasePoints,
  bb.DaysLeft,
  bb.BasePoints - sum(0) Over( order by bb.Date) AS Points,
  (bb.BasePoints - sum(0) Over( order by bb.Date)) / bb.DaysLeft AS BurnRate,
  sum(0) Over( order by bb.Date) AS BurnRateCumul
from
  burnbase as bb
order by bb.Date
```

I did also try to squash the data and approach it from a different perspective:

| Date | BasePoints | DaysLeft | DaysFor | BurnRate | TotalBurn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-09 | 6 | 82 | 4 | 0.073 | 0.292 |
| 2023-01-13 | 11 | 78 | 3 | 0.141 | 0.423 |
| 2023-01-16 | 55 | 75 | 10 | 0.7333 | 7.333 |

This still has the same issue with circular references as my basepoints would need to change based on the previous TotalBurn

I have tried various techniques from T-SQL such as recursive CTE's but Databricks SQL doesn't support these types of recursion.

I'm open to using Spark if that has a solution, I'm just not very familiar with it.

I want to create a table of data that looks like the below:

| Date | BasePoints | Points | DaysLeft | BurnRate | BurnRateCumul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 6 | 6 | 82 | 0.073 | 0.073 |
| 2023-01-02 | 6 | 5.927 | 81 | 0.073 | 0.146 |
| 2023-01-03 | 6 | 5.854 | 80 | 0.073 | 0.219 |
| 2023-01-04 | 11 | 10.871 | 79 | 0.138 | 0.357 |
| 2023-01-05 | 55 | 54.643 | 78 | 0.700 | 1.058 |

The final row should show (BurnRateCuml + BurnRate) = BasePoints

The last day should still have an amount to burn and not be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which we found was to use a standard Python loop which calls an update statement using spark passing through some parameters so we can deal with it one row at a time.

Before we go into the loop we calculated the burn rate on the first row so we have a starting point instead of having the circular reference.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Query the table and get it into a spark Dataframe
df_burndown = spark.table("ado.BurnBase")

# Convert the spark Dataframe into a pandas dataframe
results = df_burndown.select("*").toPandas()

# Set the starter row to be 2
row_num=2

# Set the max for the loop
end_row_num = results['Row_Num'].max()

#Begin the loop
while row_num<=end_row_num:

    print(row_num)
    print(end_row_num)

    df_burndown = spark.table("ado.BurnBase")
    results = df_burndown.select("*").toPandas()
    total = results['BurnRate'].sum()
    print(total)

    query="Update ado.BurnBase as bb set bb.BurnRate = (bb.BasePoints-{})/bb.DaysLeft where bb.row_num={}".format(total,row_num)

    print(query)

    spark.sql(query).show()

    row_num=row_num+1
```